# Separating responsibilities with dependencies on a central "producer" object

Tags: oop

Say you have an object that has a kind of connection to a platform or whatever. For example, an object that is used to connect to a distant web site where you can control various robots.

The producer object is used to get a dozens of instances through the connection representing these robots. These objects are dependent on the first object in that any operations are required to go through the connection. So any local code would just be putting calls through the producer object.

robots <-> connection <-> robotObjects

The originating object could have a certain number of utility methods for each of these instances that would relay changes back. However, that could turn it into a "god" class of some kind which does everything.

How would you go about separating responsibilities in a case like this ?

P.S: Feel free to suggest a better title.

Comment: You mention an existing "user object" as well as user-specific utility methods on the Facebook instance -- can you elaborate? Some sample code might help too.

Comment: @casablanca I was actually mistaken. The current graph API just returns an id for the user. Other requests are done via paths like `/me/likes/PAGE_ID`. So this is not applicable. I will edit my question.

Comment: Ok. I've reformulated the question. Hope it's clearer. Come to think of it I may have simply described the equivalent of a data and service layer or some classic pattenr :p . Would be curious to see possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds very similar to the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern):

- There is a `Robot` interface.
- The server controls the real robots through a concrete implementation, say `RealRobot`.
- The client has a `Connection` object which can return proxies that implement the `Robot` interface but forward calls through the connection to the real robots.

The `Connection` object itself would provide only basic communication methods (for eg. to send and receive data) and not contain any of the "utility methods" that you describe. The proxy implementation would make use of these communication methods to relay calls to the server.

Here's an example:

Shared interface:

```
public interface Robot {
  void move(...);
}
```

Server implementation:

```
public class RealRobot implements Robot { ... }
```

Client library:

```
public class Connection {
  public Robot getRobot(int id) {
    return new RobotProxy(id, this);
  }

  // ...
  // methods for sending and receiving data
  // ...
}

public class RobotProxy implements Robot {
  private final int id;
  private final Connection conn;

  public RobotProxy(int id, Connection conn) {
    this.id = id;
    this.conn = conn;
  }

  public void move(...) {
    conn.send("move", id, ...);
  }
}
```